# React Native: How TouchableHighlight prevent parent view get gesture responder?

Tags: react-native

There is a `TouchableHighLight` in a `View`, which specify `onStartShouldSetResponder` `onMoveShouldSetResponder` return `true`, `onResponderTerminationRequest` return `false`.
Then, only in iphone 7 plus, the TouchableHightLight's `onPress` can't be trigger when press it.

Comment: Can you clarify more what exactly you're wanting to do? i'm lost :(

Comment: Just want the TouchableHighLight can work in the View.

Comment: Maybe post the code you have? I'm sorry but your question doesn't make sense.